# How can I do syntax highlighting in JRuby?

Tags: ruby, jruby, syntax-highlighting

I'd like to use something like [ultraviolet](http://ultraviolet.rubyforge.org/) in JRuby. It (obviously) does not compile, however:

```
$ gem install ultraviolet
Fetching: oniguruma-1.1.0.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ultraviolet:
  ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        ~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby extconf.rb
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library very well.
Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.
checking for main() in -lonig... yes
creating Makefile

make
cc -I. -I. -I~/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.6.7/lib/native/include/ruby -I. -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE        -Wall  -arch x86_64 -c oregexp.c
```

Is there a similar library?

Answer (score 1):

I really like [pygments.rb](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pygments.rb/0.2.12/frames). Pygments itself is written in Python, but the integration has worked well for me. It's really fast, and best of all it supports tons of languages.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [Coderay](http://coderay.rubychan.de/)? It's pure-Ruby so no native extensions fuss. It lists support for JRuby 1.5.2+.